# GreenDAO Exception in CURD operation

Tags: android, exception, greendao

I am very new for GreenDAO. I have implement some code in Project provided by GitHub.In github there is default db know as "NOTE" and i am trying to create a new column in it for insert image.This is code to insert data in our launcher activity.

```
    Note note = new Note(null, noteText, comment, new Date() , ih.getBitmapAsByteArray(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    noteDao.insert(note);
```

and this Note.java class

```
   private byte[] img;
    public Note(Long id, String text, String comment, java.util.Date date , byte[] img) {
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
    this.comment = comment;
    this.date = date;
    this.img = img;
}
 // Setter and getter for other field and as well as for image

  public byte[] getImg(){
    return img;
}
public void setimg(byte[] img_v){
    this.img = img_v;
}
```

and this in NoteDAO.java class

```
     public static class Properties {
    public final static Property Id = new Property(0, Long.class, "id", true, "_id");
    public final static Property Text = new Property(1, String.class, "text", false, "TEXT");
    public final static Property Comment = new Property(2, String.class, "comment", false, "COMMENT");
    public final static Property Date = new Property(3, java.util.Date.class, "date", false, "DATE");
    public final static Property Image = new Property(4, Blob.class, "image", false, "IMAGE");

};     
      /** Creates the underlying database table. */
public static void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean ifNotExists) {
    String constraint = ifNotExists? "IF NOT EXISTS ": "";
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + constraint + "'NOTE' (" + //
            "'_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + // 0: id
            "'TEXT' TEXT NOT NULL ," + // 1: text
            "'COMMENT' TEXT," + // 2: comment
            "'DATE' INTEGER"+
            "'IMAGE' TEXT);"); // 3: date
}
      /** Drops the underlying database table. */
public static void dropTable(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean ifExists) {
    String sql = "DROP TABLE " + (ifExists ? "IF EXISTS " : "") + "'NOTE'";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

/** @inheritdoc */
@Override
protected void bindValues(SQLiteStatement stmt, Note entity) {
    stmt.clearBindings();

    Long id = entity.getId();
    if (id != null) {
        stmt.bindLong(1, id);
    }
    stmt.bindString(2, entity.getText());

    String comment = entity.getComment();
    if (comment != null) {
        stmt.bindString(3, comment);
    }

    java.util.Date date = entity.getDate();
    if (date != null) {
        stmt.bindLong(4, date.getTime());
    }

    byte[] img_byte = entity.getImg();
    if (img_byte != null) {
        stmt.bindBlob(5,img_byte );
    }
}

/** @inheritdoc */
@Override
public Long readKey(Cursor cursor, int offset) {
    return cursor.isNull(offset + 0) ? null : cursor.getLong(offset + 0);
}    



/** @inheritdoc */
@Override
public Note readEntity(Cursor cursor, int offset) {
    Note entity = new Note(
        cursor.isNull(offset + 0) ? null : cursor.getLong(offset + 0), // id
        cursor.getString(offset + 1), // text
        cursor.isNull(offset + 2) ? null : cursor.getString(offset + 2), // comment
        cursor.isNull(offset + 3) ? null : new java.util.Date(cursor.getLong(offset + 3)) // date
 , cursor.getBlob(offset + 4)
    );
    return entity;
}

/** @inheritdoc */
@Override
public void readEntity(Cursor cursor, Note entity, int offset) {
    entity.setId(cursor.isNull(offset + 0) ? null : cursor.getLong(offset + 0));
    entity.setText(cursor.getString(offset + 1));
    entity.setComment(cursor.isNull(offset + 2) ? null : cursor.getString(offset + 2));
    entity.setDate(cursor.isNull(offset + 3) ? null : new java.util.Date(cursor.getLong(offset + 3)));
    entity.setimg(cursor.getBlob(offset +4));
 }
```

But for all the above code i am getting a exception , Why i didn't get ?

```
      05-26 11:24:30.265: E/AndroidRuntime(3864): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable
      to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.NoteActivity}:
      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: IMAGE: , while   
      compiling: SELECT _id, TEXT, COMMENT, DATE, IMAGE FROM NOTE ORDER BY TEXT 
      COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC
```

Any help is really appreciated . Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you had already created the database on your device before and didn't take care about schema updates to your database.

You have to increase the schema version and handle updates from old schemas to your actual schema.

For development the easiest solution is to use the `DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper-class`. It will simply drop and recreate all your tables.

But I think it is good practice to implement a costum upgrade-handler even during development. This way your upgrade-mechanism gets tested "automatically" during development as your datamodel grows/gets updated.

Personally I use some code like this:

```
public class MyOpenHelper extends OpenHelper {
    public MyOpenHelper(Context context, String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
        super(context, path, factory);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Update DB-Schema: "+Integer.toString(oldVersion)+"->"+Integer.toString(newVersion));
        switch (oldVersion) {
            case 1:
                db.execSQL(SQL_1_2); 
            case 2:
                db.execSQL(SQL_2_3);
            case 3:
                db.execSQL(SQL_3_4);
        }
    }
}
```

Please notice that the `break-statements are missing on purpose. This causes my method to update the schema from the old version to the new version accross multiple versions, i.e. from version 1 to 4 by executing the statements SQL_1_2, SQL_2_3, SQL_3_4 after each other.

You can get the SQL-statements needed for version-update by comparing the table creation statements of your old generated dao-classes to the ones in your new generated dao-classes.

Answer (score 0):

In your method createTable, you have this line:

```
"'IMAGE' TEXT);"); // 3: date
```

you should change "TEXT" for BLOB, since you're handling a byte array

Comment: maybe,your database is already created, if so you could delete your data from the app before rerun with the new code.